# How hard is it to recover $p$ if I can get $h(p) \oplus h(p^*) \oplus r$ and $h(r)$?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis

Assume that $h:\{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^\lambda$ is a cryptologic hash function, $r$ is taken randomly from $\{0,1\}^\lambda$, $p$ is a low-entropy password and $p^*$ is a guess. Now we get $h(p) \oplus h(p^*) \oplus r$ and $h(r)$ but don't know $h(p)$ or $h(p^*)$.

Then there <del>are two problems</del> is a problem:

1. <del>Can we get $\Delta{}h = h(p) \oplus h(p^*)$ by a brute-force cracking?</del> (Yes.)
2. Can we get $h(p)$ (and $p$, due to the low-entropy property)?

There may be a slight different problem to consider easily, what if we get $\mathsf{pad}(p) \oplus \mathsf{pad}(p^*) \oplus r$ and $h(r)$, where $\mathsf{pad} (x)$ simply pads x with zeros?

Comment: What is the data you're starting out with?  It's unlikely that the system that you're attacking will actually provide $h(p^*)$, where $p^*$ is the value you're guessing.

Comment: Consider a system that records every login request, but for security it never stores the guess $h(p^*)$ directly? In my opinion it's common to send $h(p^*)$ instead of $p^*$ in a authentication system... Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: What's the motivation for this question?  What's the context in which you ran into it?  It seems rather strange: I can't imagine why such a system would return such a value to the attacker -- and I especially can't imagine a setting where the attacker would learn this value but wouldn't know $p^*$.  What does that even mean?  What's the distribution of $p^*$?  What do you mean by a guess?  Without that, I don't see how this question can be answered.

Comment: I have to agree. If $p^*$ was a guess, the attacker should be able to just calculate $H(p^*)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = h(p)\oplus h(p^*)\oplus r$. If $h(x) = h(r)$, then either $p = p^*$ or you've found a collision for $h$ (which happens with low probability). Since $p$ is generated from some low-entropy distribution, I assume it's feasible to brute-force over all possible values of $p$, allowing you to recover $p$ by checking whether $h(x) = h(r)$ for each guess $p^*$.

Comment: How to do this brute-force? If we've known $h(p)$, we got $y = x \oplus h(p) = h(p^*) \oplus r$, and could try every possible guess to recover the original $p^*$. Similarly,  if we've known $h(p^*)$, we got $y = x \oplus h(p^*) = h(p) \oplus r$, and could try every possible password to recover the original $p$. But we in facts know nothing about $h(p)$ or $h(p^*)$ directly.

Comment: OK, if we try every possible value of $p$ *and* $p^*$ concurrently, we may find *only one* pair $(p’,p’^*)$ that makes $h(x \oplus h(p’) \oplus h(p’^*)) = h(r)$. Then we might consider the scene $ x = \mathsf{pad}(p) \oplus \mathsf{pad}(p^*) \oplus r$. In this scene, we may find *many* pairs $(p’,p’^*)$ that $h(x \oplus \mathsf{pad}(p’) \oplus \mathsf{pad}(p’^*)) = h(r)$ . Am I right?

Comment: I assumed that you can receive $h(p)\oplus h(p^*)\oplus r$ for different values of $p^*$. Hence if you have guesses $p^*_1, p^*_2, \ldots, p^*_n$, you receive $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and compare $h(x_i)$ with $h(r)$, where $x_i = h(p)\oplus h(p^*_i)\oplus r$. If you cannot make multiple guesses, then you can recover $p$ with probability at most $\max_{p'}\Pr(p = p')$.

Comment: In my assumption, $x = h(p) \oplus h(p^*) \oplus r$ is the out-of-control thing.